# Add an unknown number of Buttons programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wrote a simple app in which I want to add some buttons programmatically. The problem is that it is not sure how many buttons have to be added. I tried to put the "Button button = new Button" into a for-loop, because I thougt it only creates a local variable. I guess that's my fault ;)

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout auswahl;

String element [] = new String [10]; //This is just an example, it would take many pages to show how this array gets created.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    auswahl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);

    element [1] = "A";
    element [2] = "B";
    element [3] = "C";
    element [4] = "D";
    element [5] = "E";
    element [6] = "F";
    element [7] = "G";
    element [8] = "H";
    element [9] = "I";
    element [0] = "J";

    int anzahl = element.length;

    for (int i = 0; i <= anzahl; i++){
        schreibeButtons(i, element[i]);
    }

}


public void schreibeButtons(int i, String string){

    Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setText(sortiment);
    button.setWidth(auswahl.getWidth());
    button.setHeight(40);
    button.setId(i*100);

    auswahl.addView(button);
} }
```

Are there any questions on what I want to reach? How to reach my aim?

Comment: first change for loop second condition to `i < anzahl` instead of `i <= anzahl` because you are initializing i with zero. second what is your question?

Comment: Man I am such an idiot -.- Thank you very much! Thats it ;)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I was typing the same in Answer bro..So can stop posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake :

```
int anzahl = element.length;
```

Array of size n contains elements from `0 to n-1,`

[prasperK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202025/k) already pointed out that.

You are adding Every Button to your `LinearLayout`  `auswahl` .

You can access your button from it only

Example : Number of Buttons - `auswahl.getChildCount()`;
And you can access each button like this

To get button 1

```
Button button1=auswahl.getChildAt(0);
```

or simply by using ID

```
Button button1=(Button)auswahl.findViewById(101);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I searched for! I'll set your answer as accepted as soon as I am possible to do that ;)